# What to do when there's no more adjustment room on disc brakes

Tags: disc-brake, adjustment

I just built up a new frame and discovered that, due to slightly different geometry the rear disc caliper can't be adjusted so that it doesn't rub. Basically I've got them all the way over to one side and it's still not enough. Can I fix this without getting new brake calipers? They're Shimano BR-M406 hydraulic caliper BTW.

Comment: I have noticed that there are two kinds of calliper attachment. Some of them have spherical washer kit onto the bolt, allowing for finer adjustment, while others are just post-mounted onto the fork/adaptor and have much less space for tuning.

Comment: What side is the issue on? Inside or out? Depending on your wheel you may be able to move the hub along the axle slightly through loosening and tightening the cones. Or you could shim the disc out a little with thin washers but don't know how safe that would be.

Comment: First make sure you've got it all assembled correctly! If you need the rotor closer to the frame you can buy sets of shimming washers for the rotor that are very accurately all the same thickness. To move it away the slightly annoying solution is a washer on the axle. Depending on the wheel setup you may be able to put that washer between the locknuts on the axle which would remove a lot of the annoyance.

Comment: @Ӎσᶎ yep, I ended up finding a washer from an old axle and putting it on axle on the side with the rotor - the disk was rubbing on the outside of the caliper. That fixed it, but the axle bolt on that side doesn't stick out the full width of the drop out now, which concerns me. When I've got the energy I'll loosen off the lock nuts and put it next to the cone, and then wind the axle through so it's even, but that's going to be a whole evenings work with adjusting the cones again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ӎσᶎ's answer was the method I went with. I just got a washer from another hub (I didn't want to use a plain old steel washer from the hardware shop because I was concerned it might be too soft, though that might not be the case) and put it on the axle next to the cone. I did that In January and it's done about 4000k without any problems since then.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy shims to put between the disc and hub. Here's one example: http://www.jensonusa.com/Syntace-Disc-Rotor-Shims

It's really that simple.

Comment: It's a good tip for people who have the opposite problem to me, but I needed the rotor to go toward the wheel - or the calliper to go away from the wheel.